# Why don't airlines install Faraday cages in their planes?

Tags: cellphones, aircraft

Cell phones and other electronic devices can interfere with the pilot's comms and other crucial avionics, as well as cell towers on the ground, if the plane is low enough. Due to these issues, the FCC forbids using cell phones on planes, while the FAA allows airlines to choose when they may be used, once the plane is out of range of the ground cell towers.<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phones_on_aircraft)</sup>

The fact is, though, many people just don't put their phones on airplane mode. You can forbid it all you want, but without enforcing it (not feasible - too many ways to get around it), it doesn't do much.

Enter the [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage).

Faraday shields are, in short, metallic surfaces that prevent the transfer of electromagnetic waves from one side to the other; Faraday cages are ones with holes in them, blocking waves of specific wavelengths while allowing all others through. You've surely seen Faraday cages before; they're in the doors of all microwaves.

This seems to be an easy (perhaps somewhat expensive) solution. Just put one up on every airplane, maybe with a wire going from one side to the other to allow the on-board Wi-Fi to still work. But it would block all outside communication, regardless of if you've got airplane mode turned on or not. If the cage is routed around/inside the sides of the planes and across the door between the cockpit and the cabin, the pilot would have no problem communicating with the outside world.

I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't put my finger on it. Is there a hole (so to speak) in this theory?

Comment: Perhaps a better fit for avionics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You said it yourself: *perhaps somewhat expensive*.  There's an unlimited number of things you could propose that would, in principle, improve safety.  But they also have to pass a cost-benefit analysis.  A particular related issue in airplanes is weight, which in turn increases fuel burn and hence operating costs.

Comment: @NateEldredge Faraday cages aren’t heavy in the slightest. I don’t know enough about them, though, to determine how expensive it would be; thus, “perhaps” somewhat expensive.

Comment: @Itai:  There's an *avionics* stack now?  Man, the stacks are really getting fragmented.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - I thinks that's a typo. There is an [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I bet the average flight has >20 phones/devices that are never turned off. This is a non-issue.

Comment: @Itai Good idea. [Done](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44306/why-dont-airlines-install-faraday-cages-in-their-planes).

Comment: My understanding is that most airplanes already *are* faraday cages, which is why it's so hard to get a GPS signal inside one unless you hold the device against the window, or at least close to it.  They obviously don't block mobile telephony frequencies as effectively, though, since it's far easier to connect a phone to the network than it is to get a GPS fix.

Comment: airlines don't really install anything in their airplanes. They ask to have them installed during the build. Ripping out the paneling and whatnot to install such a thing now would be VERY expensive. And as for weight, Boeing lists saving the weight of the flimsy plastic window shades as a selling point for the Dreamliner.

Comment: @KateGregory airlines do install and reconfigure seats relatively easily, don't they?

Comment: Have you ever actually tried putting your cell phone in the microwave? (Don't turn the microwave on.) You may be surprised at how good your cellphone is at penetrating the Faraday cage of the microwave.

Comment: @Calchas Because the microwave isn’t turned to that wavelength. If the Faraday cage was built to block out cell phone frequencies it would, but that’s not what microwaves are meant to do.

Comment: @DanielF That's true (it would have to cover a few different bands of course) but the argument here is that one could easily implement a Faraday cage to block "all outside communication" and put it in the skin of an aircraft. I have a little bit of experience with dealing with EM shielding in laboratory settings, not enough to make me an expert, but nonetheless these are big heavy structures, with very careful design around edges, joins, and doors; not just wrapping something in tin foil and hoping it works.

Comment: As an FYI, Microwave ovens are not really a Faraday cage. Most modern ones use a quarter wave choke as the door seal so the door seal is 'tuned' to attenuate the 2450MHz frequency from the magnetron and not necessarily other frequencies.

Comment: @KateGregory an airline will rip out the *entire* cabin fixtures, sidewalls, acoustic insulation and all, at least once in an aircrafts life as part of a major check - but they usually refresh a cabin several times during the aircrafts life.  Changing all the seats takes less than a week on a large aircraft, and a full cabin refresh less than a month.

Comment: @phoog GPS is a notoriously weak signal, often coming in a milliwatts per meter squared on the receiving side (it loses a tonne of power simply in the free path between the satellite and the ground, before you even start talking about going through obstacles) - its incredibly simply to block it.

Comment: What you're missing is that there are sensors/receivers all over the aircraft, including the exterior so to be effective, the cage would be the size of a hangar.  The electronics themselves are not the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Aviation electronics already are shielded to rigorous standards, such as RTCA DO-160 - the issue with cell phones and other transmitting devices is largely based on out dated scientific understanding and studies, and older requirements.

In the US, both the FCC (which is the body which actually bans cell phone use on aircraft due to issues with ground cell towers rather than interference with avionics - civil aircraft move quick enough that hand offs between cell towers can become too frequent and problematic) and the FAA (which leaves cell phone use up to airlines through exceptions to FAR 14 C.F.R § 91.21) have indicated they are willing to relax rules and change official stances, even on older aircraft.

The issue these days with cell phones on civil aircraft has rapidly shifted to social issues rather than technical issues - people don't want to be sat next to the "cell phone thug" who insists on shouting into his device for the entirety of a five hour flight.

Comment: Wouldn't most of a five-hour flight be at such an altitude that the phone would be unable to connect to the network?

Comment: @phoog 35,000ft (an average cruise altitude) is only 6.6 miles - that's nothing for a cell phone with decent line of sight.

Comment: Cell antennas are directional, and they don't point up.  A quick perusal of the internet suggests that consistent service is unavailable above roughly 6000 or 8000 feet.

Comment: @phoog all those times I've got cell phone reception at cruise over Europe and the US must be a figment of my imagination. That, or the fact that while cell phone towers direct much of their signal in specific directions, they are not shielded for other directions - it doesn't have to be straight up, since a cell phone can talk to a tower as far as 40 miles away...

Comment: @Moo I’ve never been able to connect at cruising altitude, though I have been able to do so during takeoff and landing.

Comment: @DonielF my commiserations.  What exactly do you want me to say? The FCC thinks it's an issue, and that's the crux of the rules.

Comment: Did you actually have voice calls?  Before they wired the NYC subway stations for cell service, you could nonetheless connect to the network at some (relatively shallow) spots on the 1/2/3 line under Broadway on the upper west side of Manhattan, but it was impossible to have a conversation; text messages were the only useful form of communication.

Comment: @phoog also there are proposals to add pico cells to aircraft, hence the push back from social aspects. That makes our discussion here moot.

Comment: @Moo but some planes have had satellite phones for decades.  I guess they were so expensive that the social aspects were not as significant.

Comment: @phoog using your own handset is a big plus over sat phones, plus the cost... of course, that depends on the pico cell backhaul not being over sat link itself, but it does come with significant value adds for customers to be able to just pull out their own handset, make a call and have it billed via their own provider.

Comment: @Moo BA1/3 has a pico cell on board and has done since it started. Uses satellite for backhaul. Provider comes up as "On Air". Billed at the most expensive rate I have for any country. Of course, this is nothing to do with either the FCC nor the FAA, but I guess the CAA and EASA weren't bothered.

Comment: @Calchas the CAA changed its stance in 2008.

Comment: The shielding is good enough to deal with normal levels of interference when a few phones are used, but it cannot deal with the massive amounts of interference one can potentially get if large numbers of passengers turn on their phones.

Comment: @CountIblis yes, it can. It deals with significantly more than that on an every day basis - for a start, aviation electronics have to withstand an airport surveillance radar, which averages 2.1kW and can peak at 25kW. While the aircraft isn't going to see all of that in normal use (due to how the power drops off with distance), it has to exceed likely levels - which means that it has to be able to fly close to an ASR that is transmitting at peak. That's significantly more radiation than 300 phones transmitting at peak can produce...

Comment: In addition to my last comment, current ASR radars such as ASR-9 can peak at 1.1MW. And aircraft fly close to these babies around airports!

Comment: @Moo These radar systems are designed to be able to work well with aircraft electronics, and everything is tested to see if that's indeed the case. In these clean circumstances you are not going to get the dirty intermodulation effects when you have a large number of transmitters operating at many different frequencies. Before anything is approved, tests will have to be done to prove that no such problems will happen. What matters is that the antenna doesn't even get a microwatt at the ATC  frequency, that indeed doesn't happen with ASR radar, but it's not rigorously proven for cell phones.

Answer (score -3):

Airplane safety addresses the proverbial "one in a billion risk" (which is not an exaggeration as I explain below) that a problem can occur, it doesn't deal with the normal situations where typically all will be fine. So, the fact that you won't expect problems with cell phone use in planes as pointed out in Moo's answer is not all that relevant. What matters when considering safety is if theoretically there exists a loophole that could lead to problems. One then has to make sure that such loophole cannot actually occur due to further detailed studies or by directly exposing a test flight to the theoretical risk and proving that it doesn't pose a problem.

The loophole that makes it at the moment unsafe to let people use cell phones
involves by many passengers in a plane using their phones at the same time when they all have bad reception. It is precisely the shielding due to the plane's airframe that causes poor reception. So, suppose everyone were to switch on their phones before landing (say the flight was delayed and everyone is calling home to tell that they'll arrive in half an hour). Then because the phones have very poor reception they'll crank up their output power to 1 to 2 Watt. You'll then have hundreds of phones transmitting a few hundred Watts in total inside the airframe. The electromagnetic field strength in the plane can then build up large values, each point in the plane will be exposed via direct line of sight transmissions or indirectly via reflections.

Each phone is itself blasted by the RF transmissions of all the other phones, which then causes intermodulation effects. The signal form other phones will enter your phone and that signal will be added to the signal produced by your own phone before the final amplification stage. This leads to a new signal at a frequency given by the sum or differences of the signals that are amplified. The most problematic of these are third order intermodulation signals that are the sum of two mines one other, as the frequency of that signal will be of the same order as the intended signals and these are then not blocked by the device itself.

So, the net effect is that all the phones will end up transmitting not just on their normal channels, but they'll also output strong signals at other frequencies, and these signals can then interfere with the aircraft's communication signals directly, or indirectly by causing intermodulation effects in the pilot's receiver.  While there are many filters in receivers and transmitters that block unwanted signals, they have their limits, particularly  for rejecting unwanted signals close to the frequency of the desired signal.

But suppose that the cockpit has a good RF shielding, would that not prevent problems? That's unlikely to work because of the many electric cables moving from the cockpit through the cabin. These will carry the electromagnetic fields inside the cockpit. We need to keep in mind that the plane's antenna is capturing a signal of the order of a microwatt of power and then the hundreds of watts of interference (that's not in the form of a clean signal at a totally different frequency) is going to pose a huge problem, even for the best electronics available today.

While this objection may seem far fetched, it cannot be ruled out at present that in exceptional cases you get an intermodulation signal at an ATC frequency or at a navigational beacon frequency causing a catastrophic outcome. We don't want an accident caused by cell phone induced RF interference effects every few years, but with more than 100,000 take-offs and landings per day, more than 100 million in a 3 year period, you're aiming to rule out one a billion freak incidents.